# Trying to put column head for function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying for the past hour to fix this fuction.
pandas is installed and glob
Market Cap (US$ Billion) is the name of the column
[The dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n0ci.png)
df['Market Cap (USD)'] = round(df['Market Cap (US$ Billion)']*exchange_rate ,3)
return data
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2lfp.png)
I've tried everything I can think of

data['Market Cap (USD)'] = round(data['Market Cap (US$ Billion)'] * exchange_rate, 3)
when it's suppose to work it should run through the ETL without issue but as long as i have the error I cant start the load process

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.